# Best open library for creating HTML 5/Javascript statistics page and charts

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am simply looking for the communities recommendation on an open library to help develop statistical charts, graphs, and maps for a website with HTML 5 / javascript. Something similar to what fusion charts does but without having to pay an arm and a leg and having access to the deep code.

Thank you everyone. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) and
[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) are both pretty decent. They both require JQuery.

[Raphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) is another great choice, supports all browsers including IE6.

Comment: Ive never used Protochart, at a quick glance they look ok though. I also forgot to mention Raphael, another really good one.

Comment: Good recommendations Loktar. They provide a lot of directions in which we can go. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery + any number of plugins designed just for that.

The Filament group has been doing a lot of work on that:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Dojo Charting](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2009/03/30/introducing-dojox-datachart/)

It's very nice library for charting.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google's [Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/interactive_charts.html).